# Add an XML schema to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, app-config, configuration-files

I want **Intellisense** support when writing App.config sections or XML configuration files for components like NHibernate, log4net, or Unity. What options do I have to get Visual Studio to find these files and load Intellisense?

(Assume we have the schema file.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do this.  You need to associate the schema with the document and the XML editor will then provide intellisense.  The following links go over how to achieve this

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255811.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255815.aspx

Comment: What neither of those links seem to point out is that the "schema cache folder" is the Xml\Schemas folder under the Visual Studio install path.

Comment: Neither link seems to have any information about how do add the schema.  I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255816.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Open your config file, under the properties window for your config file there is a section called 'Schemas', add your schema there.